# Show that $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} r p^r q^{n-r} = np$, given $p+q=1$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

How can I prove

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} {r} p^r q^{n-r} = np,$$
given that $p+q=1$?

I think it is about applying
$$(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} x^r.$$
Although I am quite unsure about the approach, I think it might give a way.

Comment: This is equivalent to proving the expected value of a Binomial distribution. Discussion/proofs can be found here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226237/expected-value-of-a-binomial-distribution.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I must have missed

Comment: This is closely related to [Sum $(1-x)^n$ $\sum_{r=1}^n$ $r$ $n\choose r$ $(\frac{x}{1-x})^r$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1122958), if not equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $n\ge r\ge1,$  $$r\binom nr=n\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

$$\implies\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} {r} p^r q^{n-r}  =np\sum_{r=1}^n\binom{n-1}{r-1}p^{r-1}q^{n-1-(r-1)}=np(p+q)^{n-1}$$

Comment: I think you meant $$\frac {r}{\color{red}{n}}\binom nr=\binom{n-1}{r-1}$$

Comment: @Darkrai, Thanks for the observation. The position of $=$ was messed

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues, These days, I'm too absent minded

Answer (score 4):

Another approach uses calculus. Since $\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{n}{r}x^r=(1+x)^n$, $$\sum_{r\ge 0}\binom{n}{r}rx^r=x\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n=nx(1+x)^{n-1}.$$Set $x=\frac{p}{q}$ then multiply by $q^n$, giving $$\sum_r\binom{n}{r}rp^rq^{n-r}=npq^{n-1}\left(1+\tfrac{p}{q}\right)^{n-1}=np(p+q)^{n-1}=np.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is a probabilistic approach:

- $\sum_{r=0}^{n} \binom{n}{r} r p^r q^{n-r} = E[X]$, where
- $X$ follows a binomial distribution $B(p,n)$, which means
- $X = \sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ with $X_i$ i.i.d. where $X_i \in \{0,1\}$ and $P(X_i=1) = p$
- $\Rightarrow E[X_i] = 1\cdot p + 0 \cdot (1-p) = p$

Now, it follows
$$E[X] = E \left[\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i] =\sum_{i=1}^n p = np$$